# jQuery: Click image to show div below as a box

Tags: jquery, click, hover

**What I have:**
I have three icons floating next to each-other. When I hover one of the icons a fixed sized box appear below the icon. Inside the box there are links.

**What I want:**
I want the box to stay open after I click on the icon and/or mouseout.
I want the box to close whenever I click on the icon again or when I click another icon (that in turn open a new box, for that icon in question).

**I need help with:**
I need help with adjusting/change the script I am currently using for the hover effect. Anyone?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fb-icon").hover( function() {
        $("#fb-icon-content").css('display','block');
    }, function() {
        $("#fb-icon-content").hide();
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**
After several hours of testing I found that this script created what I needed:

```
$('#expand-facebook').click(function() {
$('#facebook-expanded').toggle('slow', function() {
}); });
```

Comment: Do you want the box to come down when you hover, or when you click?

Comment: I want the box to drop when I click an icon. When I click another icon the first box should slideUp and the new one should slideDown.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/8T8sA/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="ico"></li>
    <li class="ico"></li>
    <li class="ico"></li>
</ul>

<div id="fb-icon-content">some content</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
.ico {
    margin-left:50px;
    width:32px; height:32px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#fb-icon-content {
    position:fixed;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
var shown = false;

$(".ico").hover( function() {
    if ( shown === false ) {
        var that = $(this),
            offset = that.offset(),
            tooltipElement = $("#fb-icon-content");

        tooltipElement.css({
            top: offset.top + that.height() + 10,
            left: offset.left + that.width()/2 - tooltipElement.width()/2
        }).show();
    }
}, function() {
    if ( shown === false ) {   
        $("#fb-icon-content").hide();
    }
}).bind('click', function() {
    var tooltipElement = $("#fb-icon-content"),
        that = $(this);

    if ( shown === that.index() ) {
        tooltipElement.hide();
        shown = false;
    } else {
        shown = $(this).index();

        var that = $(this),
            offset = that.offset(),
            tooltipElement = $("#fb-icon-content");

        tooltipElement.css({
            top: offset.top + that.height() + 10,
            left: offset.left + that.width()/2 - tooltipElement.width()/2
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: how did you get that to save!  ;(  JSFiddle isn't saving for me.

Comment: @czerasz Your reply give me the hover effect, I was asking for a hover function that would bring me a box that is visible until I click the same icon again or another icon :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem you are having is when you move out of the icon to the menu, the menu goes away because the "unhover" event gets fired on #fb-icon?

You might want to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // to show when clicked
    $("#fb-icon").click( function() { 
        // hide the previously opened content
        if (window.lastContent != null )
            window.lastContent.css('display','none'); 

        window.lastContent = $("#fb-icon-content");
        window.lastContent.css('display','block'); 
    });
    // show the icon content when hover on the icon
    $("#fb-icon").hover( function() { 
        window.lastContent = $("#fb-icon-content");
        window.lastContent.css('display','block'); 
    }); 
});
```

However, it looks like you have only one #fb-icon-content. Shouldn't you have one per icon?

Comment: Omar: I did not want to bother you all with all the code. The script is most important, the CSS is secondary here.